# Imhomegenous Wave Equation: Possible Born and Wolf Error

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, textbook-erratum

My concern involves the following lines from Principle of Optics (Born and Wolf 7th ed, 60 year anniverary, Section 1.2 pg 11).  I fail to derive these equations 5,6 exactly.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla^2E -\frac{\varepsilon\mu}{c^2}\partial^2_t E+\nabla(\ln\mu)\times(\nabla \times E)+\nabla(E\cdot\nabla(\ln\varepsilon))&=0 \tag{5}\\
\nabla^2H -\frac{\varepsilon\mu}{c^2}\partial^2_t H+\nabla(\ln\varepsilon)\times(\nabla \times H)+\nabla(H\cdot\nabla(\ln\mu))&=0 \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

No matter how many times I do the derivation I keep getting the same result (which differ from the text).

The discrepancy starts when you go from
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\varepsilon}{c^2}\partial^2_t E+\nabla\times\left(\frac{1}{\mu}\nabla \times E\right)&=0 \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$
which arises from taking the curl of Maxwell's equations. Expansion via
$$
\nabla\times(u \mathbf v)=u\nabla\times \mathbf v+\nabla u \times \mathbf v\\
\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf v = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf v)-\nabla^2 \mathbf v  
$$

and the other Maxwell's equations

$$
\nabla \cdot (\varepsilon E)=0 \\
\nabla \cdot (\mu H) = 0 \\
$$

gives me the following instead.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla^2E -\frac{\varepsilon\mu}{c^2}\partial^2_t E-\nabla(\ln\mu)\times(\nabla \times E)+\nabla(E\cdot\nabla(\ln\varepsilon))&=0 \tag{mine}\\
\nabla^2H -\frac{\varepsilon\mu}{c^2}\partial^2_t H-\nabla(\ln\varepsilon)\times(\nabla \times H)+\nabla(H\cdot\nabla(\ln\mu))&=0 \tag{mine}
\end{align}
$$

where the 3rd term signs are flipped relative to the equations in the text. I've checked older.

I've checked another text , Mathematical Theory of Optics (Luneberg) which seems to have an identical result but it reference Born and Wolf so for all I know it just copies it.

To me the $\nabla^2 E$ term simply has to have the opposite sign of the $\nabla(\ln\mu)\times(\nabla \times E)$ term.

I suspect I made an error somewhere in my derivation but I just can't see where it could be. I've spent few hours and can't seem to find where I could have made the sign error.

I also tried searching the book [website](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/principles-of-optics/D12868B8AE26B83D6D3C2193E94FFC32#fndtn-contents) for an errata

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just checked it, B&W is right: it is $+$. you may have forgotten the $-$ in Faraday's law.

Comment: Did you also get equation (2) above? I started with (2) in B+W. Did you derive from scratch?

Comment: took the curl of Faraday's eq, and expanded it $\nabla \times (\nabla \times E)=-\nabla \times \mu \dot H$, took the time diff of Maxwell-Ampere $\nabla \times \dot H = -\mu \ddot E$ and $\nabla \cdot \epsilon E=0$, that is all.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I resolved my sign error.

It was related to how $\nabla \ln \mu= -\mu \nabla(\frac{1}{\mu})$ I missed the negative sign there.

A silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issues with Born and Wolf text, I made a mistake in my mathematical calculation. Specifically I should have paid attention to

$\nabla \ln \mu= -\mu \nabla(\frac{1}{\mu})$